# Permission Denied Error in IE While changing URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer, permission-denied

I am opening a popup window from main(parent) window and passing main windows cookie for session.

Both window are different sites and I use cookie to share some information. That is main window from site www.site1.com and opening popup window of www.site-two.com.

However if i logged out main (parent) window and cleared session cookie, then i refresh popup window in IE says, permission denied.

But works fine in Firefox, Chrome.

In site-two.com, popup.html

```
<script src="www.site1.com/JS/logoff.js" />
```

In Site1.com's logoff.js

```
function ClosePopup(){

 self.opener.location = self.location.href; // Error permission denied
```

}

All the properties of **self.opener** are all saying 'Access Denied'

What could be the reason? Any help are appreciated !!

Comment: On which domains are the two pages?

Comment: Both are two different server but shared domain name. Like one is in US with name of application1.somecompanydomain.com and another is in UK with name of application2.somecompanydomain.com . But both are different server machines

Comment: The machines are not interesting, but the two different subdomains are the root of your problem. Not sure how to fix it for IE, though, so I can't answer it...

Comment: Sites are HTTPS configured,but it says Un trusted Certificate and red color in url bar. Do you think this certificate issue may be the reason ? I also thinking in that way.

Comment: Don't you need your script tag to be formatted as follows, as you are missing the required closing tag for `script` and the protocol? `<script src="http://www.site1.com/JS/logoff.js"></script>`

Comment: Script tag is not an issue. I gave the code sample to let the user to know how i am referring. However i used self closing HTML tag. so no issues!

Comment: Can you set `document.domain = 'somecompanydomain.com'`? Does the page that is loaded after logout contain this code?

Answer (score 0):

This is for Untrusted Uncertificate relates issues...

To work around this issue, add the Web site that is affected to the Trusted sites security zone in Internet Explorer. To do this, follow these steps:
Start Internet Explorer.
On the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
On the Security tab, click Trusted sites, and then click Sites.
In the Add this Web site to the zone box, type the URL of the Web site that is affected, and then click Add.
Click OK.

Comment: We dont use any certificates. From my understanding its cross domain communication issue